The AWS Timestream Batch Upload can't reuse Timestream UNLOAD
I have a very annoying problem with AWS Timestream UNLOAD and then Batch Upload functionality.
I'm using only one custom dimension, let's call it: module.
I want to migrate all of the contents of that table to another table in another account. I have successfully backed up data using UNLOAD to S3, migrated the data to another account, and now try to reupload it back using Batch Upload from Timestream. However, I use default columns: measure_name and measure_value (which is a multi value column: measure_value::double, measure_value::varchar etc.).
During Batch Upload task configuration it asks to create a source-target mapping, and whatever I try, I can't make it work.
It requires at least time, measure_name and MULTI value columns. Which I set of course, but then it complains that measure_value is actually a reserved word.
Da!
Is there some kind of magic workaround, am I doing something wrong, or is that functionality fundamentally broken?
